# JavaDoc formatting in IntellIj

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatting, javadoc

How can I tell IntelliJ to stop doing:

```
/**
  *
  *
```

and do this instead:

```
/**
 *
 *
```

Comment: Are you sure you use the default IntelliJ IDEA formatter and not some third-party plug-in? In IntelliJ IDEA [the second example is the default](https://i.imgur.com/Zfr6Jr8.png) and there is no way to change it.

Comment: Hmmm. If I do, it's not intentional.

Comment: What third-party plug-ins do you have installed? Any `.editorconfig` files in the project?

Comment: Not that I can tell. I'll go through my plugins.